# Help solving: Normal Distribution problem without using the table OR with a given std

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

For a recent history test, scores follow the normal distribution with a mean of 70 points. 80% of the students scored below 88 points. What is the standard deviation of the scores?

I have done a lot of research into the question and eventually broke down and used the standard table. The answer I got through that was a std of 21.387.

I know I need to use the z score formula (x-mean)/std = z   but I am searching for two of those variables and would need the z score at least to find the std.

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use the standard table?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. The professor told us up front that the table with not be given on exams and therefore shouldn't be used on outside assignments to give us better practice. It's ridiculous, I know. But he says it's possible to do.

Comment: Then the professor would be the person to ask about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see how to answer this question with pencil and paper only--no tables, no calculators--is to have the quantiles of the standard normal distribution memorized:

$$\begin{align*} \Pr[Z \le 0.8] &\approx 0.842 \\ \Pr[Z \le 0.9] &\approx 1.282 \\ \Pr[Z \le 0.95] &\approx 1.645 \\ \Pr[Z \le 0.975] &\approx 1.96 \\ \Pr[Z \le 0.995] &\approx 2.576. \end{align*}$$  Most statisticians should be familiar with all but the first one.  The first one is not commonly encountered.

One can also remember the 68-95-99.7 rule (also called the "empirical rule"):  $$\begin{align*} \Pr[-1 \le Z \le 1] &\approx 0.68, \\ \Pr[-2 \le Z \le 2] &\approx 0.95, \\ \Pr[-3 \le Z \le 3] &\approx 0.997.\end{align*}$$

But if none of these memorized values apply, then I don't see how it is reasonable to do the calculation with sufficient precision to be meaningful.  If you have a calculator such as a TI-83, you can use the `invNorm()` and `normalcdf()` functions.